# Font size of UI for Enterprise Architect Sparx

Tags: enterprise-architect

how can I increase the font size of the UI of EA Sparx?

I mean the font for the entire EA application and NOT for particular elements in a diagram.

So i.e. the item's name of tree elements is too small and I need to take a second glass to read it. Bzw the title for control elements is small as well.

many thanks in advance

Comment: For diagrams Configure/Options. For the rest: set the resolution in windoze

Comment: This is related to scaling for large DPI monitors. Play with those settings a bit to find the best for EA.